# Account that has related contacts should not be deleted

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to write a trigger in which if an account that has related contacts and the user tries to delete that account it throws you an error..

```
trigger DoNotDeleteAccountHavingRelatedContact on Account (before insert, before update)  
{  
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();  
    Set<id> accIdSet = new Set<id>();  
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)  
    {  
        accIdSet.add(acc.id);  
    }  

Map<Id,Contact> mapContacts = new Map<Id,Contact>([Select lastname,id,accountid 
                                        From Contact Where Accountid 
                                        IN : accIdSet]);

for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
{
    if(mapContacts.get(acc.id).contacts.size()>0)
    {
        acc.adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
    }
}                                       

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your trigger is a Before Insert/Update. Try:

`trigger DoNotDeleteAccountHavingRelatedContact on Account (before delete)`

And do replace `Trigger.new` with `Trigger.old`

** UPDATE **

Another commenter raised the issue that there was also a code problem. Please find an updated sample below

```
trigger DoNotDeleteAccountHavingRelatedContact on Account (before delete)  
{  
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();  
    Set<id> accIdSet = new Set<id>();  
    for(Account acc : Trigger.old)  
    {  
        accIdSet.add(acc.id);  
    }  

    Map<Id, Account> accts = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id, (Select Id from contacts) from Account where id in :accIdSet]);

    for(Account acc : Trigger.old)
    {
        if(accts.get(acc.id).contacts.size()>0)
        {
            acc.adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
            }
        }                                       

}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Comment: Awesome! Mark it as accepted it if worked so others can see the solution and benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am wrong, the query will fill your map with the Contact.id => Contact not with the AccountId. So the get call on the map will return null.

Here is what I would do:

```
trigger DoNotDeleteAccountsWithContacts on Account(before delete) {
Set<Id> accountsWithContacts = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId in :trigger.oldMap.keySet()]) {
    accountsWithContacts.add(c.AccountId);
}
for(Id id : accountsWithContacts) {
    trigger.oldMap.get(id).addError('Account cannot be deleted while there are related contacts');
}
```

}

Comment: I like your solution, and I've adapted mine to use the concept you mention. The reason why I adapted from yours (Instead of pointing to it) is that you are iterating over every contact, and there is no need to do that.

Comment: I like your solution by including the contacts in the query itself. I think you can skip looping through the accounts to put them in a set by just calling Trigger.oldMap.keySet() in your query. I'd comment on your answer but I'm new to the community and still can't comment on other people's answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could also query for accounts that have contact records and prevent those from being deleted like:

```
trigger DoNotDeleteAccountHavingRelatedContact on Account (before delete)  
{  
    for(Account acc : [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact) AND Id IN :Trigger.oldMap.KeySet()]){
        Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
    }
}
```

Comment: @anzar have you tried this solution ?

Comment: @Bennie yeah its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger preventDeleteOnAccount on Account (before Delete) {
    List<Id> accId = new List<Id>();
    List<Account> acclst = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)];
    for(Account ac : acclst){
        accId.add(ac.Id);
    }
    for(Account acc : Trigger.old){
         if(accId.contains(acc.Id)){
            acc.adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
         }
    }
}
```